# Flask SqlAlchemy Classical Mappings MAny To Many

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I would like to see some example about classical mappings and many to many relations in SQLAlchemy.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having difficulty in mapping many to many relationships using classical mapping. I could not solve yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can find multiple examples here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html

Association proxy is the most common many-to-many pattern, see example at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/association/proxied_association.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am having difficulty in mapping many to many relationships using classical mapping. I could not solve yet.